# Principal bundle built from equivariant CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

The Milnor join construction of classifying space for $G$ is a $G$-equivariant CW complex $\mathcal{J}(G) = \lim_{k\to \infty}{G^{*(k+1)}}$ which admits a free $G$-action.  Then the projection $p: \mathcal{J}(G) \to \mathcal{J}(G)/G$ defines a principal $G$-bundle.  My question is why does it qualify as a principal $G$-bundle?  Is this true in general for any $G$-equivariant CW complex with a free $G$-action?

Answer (score 0):

A principal G-bundle is a space which admits a free and transitive G-action, but the action on a G-equivariant complex need not be transitive. The G-equivariance doesn't refer to the topology of the complex, just to the Homs of the category it sits inside.

Comment: This is not correct, you don't need the action to be transitive. Think of the universal $\mathbb{Z}/2$-bundle $S^{\infty} \to \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$. The action of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $S^{\infty}$ is not transitive.

Comment: Wait.  I am confused.  Do I need to check transitivity or not if given the $G$-equivariance?  On the other hand in the current context of Milnor join construction of classifying space is the transitivity automatic?